# Nginx running on docker not redirecting requests correctly

Tags: javascript, docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I've two servers running on my system at port 3000 and 3001.
I'm trying to implement nginx reverse proxy but failed to achieve the result.

Here are my files
server1.js

```
const http = require("http");

const hostname = "127.0.0.1";
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
  res.end("Hello World\n");
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

server2.js

```
const http = require("http");

const hostname = "127.0.0.1";
const port = 3001;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
  res.end("Hello World from server 2\n");
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
    location /app1/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3030/;
    }
    location /app2/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3031/;
    }
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - PATH_OF_NGINX.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

All files are present in same folder.

This is the error which nginx gives
[image]

Comment: In Docker, `localhost` and the equivalent IPv4 address 127.0.0.1 usually refer to the current container, not the host system.  Do you need to know [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) to proxy to the non-container processes?

Comment: If nginx server and client both are running on the docker container, then also it needs to add host.docker.internal. Why so?

Comment: Do you have 3 containers? The configuration is unclear.

Comment: I've only one container which is running nginx. Other two servers are running on my local system.

Comment: @jabaa Also can you please tell me which configuration is unclear?

Comment: Ok, now everything is clear, and the dupe target is correct. Unrelated to your problem: The client seems to be a browser. It runs on your host system, not in the container. But it makes no difference.